# Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython2.7.so.1.0

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-wsgi

I've been working for the past 2 days trying to get mod_wsgi setup properly so it will work with my virtualenv and Django site in Python 1.7.

```
[root@server mod_wsgi-3.4]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've read this: https://serverfault.com/a/628728/211505 but following those instructions did not change anything.

I can confirm that `libpython2.7.so.1.0` is in `/usr/local/lib`. Any ideas on how to proceed?

More info:

```
[root@server mod_wsgi-3.4]# httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_alias_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_default_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 ldap_module (shared)
 authnz_ldap_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 usertrack_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 speling_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 disk_cache_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: which is the centos version you have? I am having centos 7. mod_wsgi can be installed via yum. Please share the out put of httpd -M

Comment: I added that to the post. It is Cent OS 6.

Comment: Exactly what did you do to the system?

Comment: I've tried recompiling Python to a higher version, reinstalling virtualenv, pip, mod_wsgi manually, trying to get things to come together